# Laravel Elixir - Execute cmd on watch update

Tags: laravel-elixir

I'm trying to create an easy workflow for package development and was hoping someone could pint me in the right direction. In short, once a css file has been updated I want to be able to run a command (`php artisan vendor:publish --force`) to automatically publish the files.

Can this be done with Elixir and if so could anyone point me in the right direction?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone is looking, this works nicely:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var shell = require("gulp-shell");
var elixir = require("laravel-elixir");

elixir.extend("publish", function() {
    var baseDir = this.assetsDir;
    gulp.task("publish_assets", function() {
        gulp.src("").pipe( shell( [
            "php ../../../artisan vendor:publish --force",
            "cd ../../../ ; gulp"
        ]));
    });
    this.registerWatcher("publish_assets", [
        baseDir + '**/*.scss',
        baseDir + '**/*.js'
    ]);
    return this.queueTask("publish_assets");
});
```

Comment: you could also remove `"cd ../../../ ; gulp"` and just run gulp watch in another terminal

Answer (score 1):

This was incredibly useful to get me on the right track, but I found a slightly simpler solution that I thought I would share:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
var gulp = require("gulp");
var shell = require("gulp-shell");

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.task('publish_assets', ['resources/assets/**/*.scss', 'resources/assets/**/*.js']);
});

gulp.task('publish_assets', shell.task([
    "php ../../../../artisan vendor:publish --tag=public --force"
]));
```

It watches all of the js and sass files for changes and runs the publish assets task. Mine is set to only publish the "public" tagged files, and a quick note as well, you will need to install the gulp-shell utility (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-shell) for either of these.